Generate vectors with a certain property
I want to generate ALL vectors of size $n$ (i am only interested in values of n=2,...,7) with Mathematica, which satisfy the following property:
The first entry $x_1=0$ and for subsequent entries $x_{k+1}=0$ or $x_{k+1}=x_{k}+1$.
However I have not found in my internet search any code that generates them and honestly I don't know how to do it myself.
An example of a vector of size 5 is: $[0,1,2,3,0]$.
An example of a vector of size 5 that does not satisfy this property is:: $[0,1,2,1,0]$, this is because $x_4=1$ does not satisfy that $x_{4}=x_{3}+1$.

Solution without recursion.
gen[n_Integer?Positive] := FoldList[#2 (#1 + #2) &, 0, #] & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, n - 1]

For n = 5
gen[5]


{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 2}, 
 {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 2, 3}, 
 {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 2}, 
 {0, 1, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}}


It is also reasonably fast for larger n; over 4-times faster than recursive step solution.
RepeatedTiming[gen[20];]


{0.425884, Null}


versus
n = 20; (*vector length*)
ini = {0}; (*start vec*)
RepeatedTiming[Flatten[step[ini], n - 2];]


{1.79392, Null}


Hope this helps

This calls for a recursive function.
n=5; (*vector length*)
ini={0}; (*start vec*)

step[in_] := (If[Length[in] == n, 
    Return[in], {step[Append[in, 0]], 
     step[Append[in, in[[-1]] + 1]]}]);

Flatten[step[ini], n - 2]


